# Iterate through columns' suffixes in a for loop. R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to modify my dataset with a for loop. I want to modify certain cells of some columns depending on the value of its "paired" column. My dataset could be:

```
data1989 <- data.frame("date" = c("1987-01-01", "1987-01-03", "1987-01-19"), 
                       "NDVI_1" = c(NA, 0.589, 0.120), 
                       "NDVI_3" = c(NA, 0.447, NA), 
                       "NDVI_4" = c(NA, NA, NA),
                       "pixelQA_1" = c(NA, 66.897,90.599), 
                       "pixelQA_3" = c(NA, 66.097,NA),
                       "pixelQA_4" = c(NA, NA, NA),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

> data1989
        date NDVI_1 NDVI_3 NDVI_4 pixelQA_1 pixelQA_3 pixelQA_4
1 1987-01-01     NA     NA     NA        NA        NA        NA
2 1987-01-03  0.589  0.447     NA    66.897    66.097        NA
3 1987-01-19  0.120     NA     NA    90.599        NA        NA
```

Columns are "paired" by the suffix of each column, so `NDVI_1` is paired with `pixelQA_1`, and so on. I want to modify the values under `NDVI`'s columns depending on it's "paired" values on `pixelQA` column, following:

- if PixelQa is NA -> then NDVI should be also NA.
- if Pixel Qa is 66±0.5 OR 130±0.5 -> then NDVI remains the same value.
- if Pixel Qa is different to 66±0.5 OR 130±0.5 -> then NDVI value is set to NA (this is bad quality data which needs to be ignored).

Applying these very simple rules my data should look like:

```
data1989clean <- data.frame("date" = c("1987-01-01", "1987-01-03", "1987-01-19"), 
                       "NDVI_1" = c(NA, NA, NA), 
                       "NDVI_3" = c(NA, 0.447, NA), 
                       "NDVI_4" = c(NA, NA, NA),
                       "pixelQA_1" = c(NA, 66.897,90.599), 
                       "pixelQA_3" = c(NA, 66.097,NA),
                       "pixelQA_4" = c(NA, NA, NA),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> data1989clean
        date NDVI_1 NDVI_3 NDVI_4 pixelQA_1 pixelQA_3 pixelQA_4
1 1987-01-01     NA     NA     NA        NA        NA        NA
2 1987-01-03     NA  0.447     NA    66.897    66.097        NA
3 1987-01-19     NA     NA     NA    90.599        NA        NA
```

To reach my goal I am trying the following for loop:

```
for(i in 1:4){
  data1989$NDVI_[i] <- ifelse(data1989$pixelQA_[i] < 66.5 & data1989$pixelQA_[i] > 65.5 |
                              data1989$pixelQA_[i] < 130.5 & data1989$pixelQA_[i] > 129.5,
                              data1989$NDVI_[i], NA)
  }
```

But so far it is not working, as the dataset output looks exactly the same as the original one. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: You need to use the format `data1989[, paste0("pixelQA_", i)]` to access columns in that way.  You can't use the `$` notation if the column name is a variable.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! If I change into: `for(i in 1:4){
  data1989[, paste0("NDVI_", i)] <- ifelse(data1989[, paste0("pixelQA_", i)] < 66.50 & data1989[, paste0("pixelQA_", i)] > 65.5 |
                                           data1989[, paste0("pixelQA_", i)] < 130.5 & data1989[, paste0("pixelQA_", i)] > 129.5,
                                           data1989[, paste0("NDVI_", i)], NA)
  }` I keep having the error `Error in [.data.frame``(data1989, paste0("pixelQA_", i)) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but the way to do this is to reshape your dataset (using for example 'tidyr::pivot_longer') so that there is only a single NDVI and a single pixelQA column, then perform your coding operations, then reshape it back to the original shape.

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo The reason it fails is that your loop includes `i=2` but your data does not have columns with that suffix.  Perhaps you want `for(i in c(1,3,4))`.

Comment: It was definitely that. Thanks Andrew! That makes my life simpler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @George Savva, you can achieve this by pivoting longer, correcting the data, and pivoting back wider. So, using the `tidyverse`, that gives:

```
library(tidyverse)

newdd1 <-
  #
  data1989 %>%
  #
  pivot_longer(cols = -date,
               names_to = c(".value", "set"),
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  #
  mutate(NDVI = case_when(is.na(pixelQA) ~ NA_real_,
                          between(pixelQA, 65.5, 66.5) ~ NDVI,
                          between(pixelQA, 129.5, 130.5) ~ NDVI,
                          TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
  #
  pivot_wider(names_from = set,
              values_from = c(NDVI, pixelQA))
```